# How to bind CheckBoxes from GridView to source DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to create some form, in which users can create multiple tests for some data. If user want to validate data, he must check Checkbox in appropiate row and column for a test and then, click button titled "Validate tests". If user want to add new test (i.e. Test2), he must press "Add test" button.

All data are stored into DataTable (dtTests) and displaying by GridView (dgvTests) on aspx page.

My question is, how can i get checked-values for each checkboxes ?

**Example website:**
In Example, user add two tests (look on image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR8l5.jpg).

- In Test1, he want to validate years: 1990, 1993, 1999
- In Test2, he want to validate years: 1990, 1993, 1998, 1999

**New Test column in dtTests:**

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Test" + i.ToString())
{
    DataType = typeof(Boolean),
    ReadOnly = false    
};
dtTests.Column.Add(dc);
```

**I add new TestX column to gridView in this way:**

```
TemplateField cbxTest = new TemplateField();
cbxTest.HeaderTemplate = new CheckBoxTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, "Test" + i.ToString(), "Test" + i.ToString());
cbxTest.ItemTemplate = new CheckBoxTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "Test" + i.ToString(), "Test" + i.ToString());
dgvTests.Columns.Add(cbxTest);
```

**Here's class for CheckBoxTemplate:**

```
public class CheckBoxTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        private DataControlRowType templateType;
        private string columnName;
        private string bindName;

        public CheckBoxTemplate(DataControlRowType _type, string _colName, string _bindName)
        {
            templateType = _type;
            columnName = _colName;
            bindName = _bindName;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            switch (templateType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    Literal lc = new Literal() { Text = String.Format("<b>{0}</b>", columnName) };
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;

                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();
                    cbx.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.cbx_DataBinding);
                    container.Controls.Add(cbx);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void cbx_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)cbx.NamingContainer;
            cbx.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, bindName).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try assigning them a cssclass then query for that using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can go about it, first assign an id to your checkboxes `cbx.ID = "cbxDoTest`.

Then add a `RowCommand` event handler that will be triggered when your **Validate tests** button is clicked. Here you need to traverse the `e.Row.Cells` properties, if the cell belonged to a test column then do a search on the checkbox control (`Checkbox cbx = e.Row.Cell[i].FindControl("cbxDoTest");` then check if the `cbx.Checked` is true or false.

I wrote the flow and how to do it from my head so double check the method/property names.

Comment: Sir i have the same problem with link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929061/asp-net-gridview-rowdata-is-coming-empty-and-unchecked"...Please help me on this..