# Asp.net Gridview Rowdata is coming empty and Unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, custom-controls

I have a requirement where i need to add column names and rowdatabound values dynamically .I has managed to get Column names dynamically .According to my need i want values to be displayed in the form of checkboxes in the rows of the grid either in checked form or unchecked based on condition but here every thing is coming in unchecked formate ..

I am using .net membership  Role table...

Here is my code for gridview Dynamic column allocation..

```
protected void BindGridviewData()
{

    var role = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
               select new
               {
                   User = u.UserName,
                   Role = string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName))
               };


    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    string[] rolesarr = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    // add column for user name 
    dTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    // then add all the roles as columns 
    Array.ForEach(rolesarr, r => dTable.Columns.Add(r));

    List<string> tempfield = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dTable.Columns)
    {
       string ColName = column.ColumnName;
       tempfield.Add(ColName);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tempfield.Count; i++)
    {

    string tempfieldname = tempfield[i];
    TemplateField temp = new TemplateField();
    if (i == 0)
    {
        temp.HeaderText = tempfieldname;

        tempfieldname = string.Empty;
    }
    else {

        temp.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate();
        temp.HeaderText = tempfieldname;
        tempfieldname = string.Empty;
    }
    GridView1.Columns.Add(temp);
    }
```

Now Here i am checking values to be checked or uncked..

```
foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = u.UserName;

        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);

        dRow[1] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("DPAO User") ? true : false;
        dRow[3] = roles.Contains("GeneralUser") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Upto here values are coming fine in **dTable** but once flow goes to rowdatabound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

}
```

On rowdatabound event flow automatically moves to **custom control** class which is ...

```
public class MyTemplate : ITemplate
  {
public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
{
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.ID = "chk";
    container.Controls.Add(chk);
}

}
```

And from here all checkboxes are displaying as unchecked ...

Please guys help me ..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should show us your asp.net code for the grid

Answer (score -1):

Do it in this way. check where the column is true false in the rowDatabound event and the add control here only.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        if(e.Row.Cells["Column Name"].toString == true ){
             cb.Checked = true; 
        }else{
             cb.Checked = false;   
        }
        e.Row.Cells["Column Name"].Controls.Add(cb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u sir for ur response ..Actually i needed column names and values to be added dynamically .no hard coding .Thts why i used Custom control of checkbox and Wrote loops to get column names

Comment: I am sorry but you coding is not dynamic cause while creating template your code can handle as many columns you like. but while checking in for loop you have just four columns Fixed. Each row has four cols only. So you are always binding a four columns GV always. be clear with your objective sir. I am sorry if i wrote something wrong

Comment: Thanks for ur response sir.for this time i need it for four columns only first one will be username column and rest are of checkbox type..